# How to keep search state after typing?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

i made a table to get remote data **it's working but after the results received the input automatically cleared** so i want it be there **how can i do this?**

**this is the behavior**

plz notice that in the below picture when i type something the top left search field the result cleared automatically when the request for remote data starts, i don't know why this happening but ican tell u that the same component used in different app but this behavior is not there

[image]

here is my `table component` code

```js
import Event from '~/Services/Event';
const event = new Event();
@withStyles(styles)
@observer
class Table extends React.Component {
  // Mobx State
  @observable exceptionErrorsLoader= true;
  @observable exceptionError= null;
  state = {
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: 10,
    query: {},
    oldQuery: {},
    enableColumnFiltering: this.props.enableColumnFiltering,
  }
  get(query) {
    // get Logic Here
  }
  render() {
      return (
        <Entity
          storeId={this.props.storeId}
          entityRef={ref => { this.entity = ref; }}
          onEntityReceived={data => this.onEntityReceived(data)}
          render={store => (
              <MaterialTable
                tableRef={ref => this.tableRef = ref}
                data={query => {
                  this.get(query);
                  return new Promise(resolve => event.on('data-fetched', resolve));
                }}
                columns={this.props.columns}
              />
          )}
        />
      );
  }
}
export default Table;
```

FYI, i used this component in another project **it worked fine like this**
[image]

Also i need to understand how state in material-table works if u can help me i'll be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are reseting the search query, because you pass the old query in `this.tableRef.onQueryChange(this.state.oldQuery);`.

The query also contains the search text. But the previous query had no search text, and it will get reset, if you set the old query.
Try something like this:

```
  refreshDataWithDefaultFilters(newQuery) {
    // To refresh current table data based on Old_QUERY
    this.tableRef && this.tableRef.onQueryChange({...this.state.oldQuery, search: newQuery.search});
  }
```

Comment: here i reset with the default as the user enter the page for first time this is not the problem, i meant this behavior, plus this method called when i click on refresh button in the top left not during getting data.